# AsyncStorage.getItem("item") returns the string "[object Object]"

Tags: react-native

I'm using `AsyncStorage` in order to save a "session" in my app, and I do so in this piece of code:

```js
if (signInResult) {
    if (signInResult.userId && signInResult.accessToken) {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem("auth", signInResult);
    }
    this.props.navigation.navigate("home");
}
```

But when I tried to get the data back with `AsyncStorage.getItem("auth")`, it just retrieves the string `[object Object]`

I tweaked the code a but to write stuff in the console so I could keep tabs on the data, so here's what I encountered so far:

[image]

[image: Console]

So there I logged the same data before and after putting it "through" the `AsyncStorage`. First, we see that the object is still very much a javascript object, and the second is just the name o the type, apparently. I'm not sure what's going on here, but I'm pretty sure this should work. I actually use that same approach in another app and I don't have this issue there.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `JSON.stringify` & `JSON.parse` while saving and getting data from AsyncStorage.

```js
if (signInResult) {
  if (signInResult.userId && signInResult.accessToken) {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem("auth", JSON.stringify(signInResult));
  }
  AsyncStorage.getItem("auth").((item) => {
    JSON.parse(item);
  });

  this.props.navigation.navigate("home");
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that was it. Which makes me wonder why the code works on the other app. Thanks!